# Asp.net app_data folder contains db

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, app-data

I am using VS 2005

I am new to asp.net i have a project created in asp.net c# which is using sql server express edition local database.

there is a app_data folder there is *.mdf file inside i can see it also i can browse the tables from it.

In app data folder i can see there are few .sql scripts

named
CreateAllObjects.sql
DeleAllData.sql
EnableConstaints.sql

when i run project i found few procedures are required and their scripts exists in "CreateAllObjects.sql" but problem is i don't know in vs.net IDE how can execute these .sql scripts to create objects please help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have SQL Server Management Studio Express to run these scripts. When installed you can just double click and run these scripts on your databases. Cheers.

Comment: how can i connect app_data db with studio express?

Comment: In Management Studio Express, right click and select attach database, then select your App_Data file.